# Why does Finder keeping showing me menus in Spanish?

Tags: macos, finder, spanish

The bottom of my menus, when I command-click on a file in Finder, are in Spanish:

[image]

How can I stop this from happening? I'm sure I inadvertently hit a key combination that did this, but I'm stumped as to what that was. My System Preference settings for Language & Text have the language set to Canadian English.

This has happened before, with a full reboot fixing it. This time however it has no effect.

Comment: Is this only in Finder or any contextual menu?

Comment: Only in the Command-Click menu that appears for filed and folders in Finder.

Comment: I think you mean Control-click (i.e. ‘right click’), not Command-click. That is not Spanish. Looks more like Portuguese. Seems like the translated version of “Configure Folder Actions…”.

Comment: Yes, sorry, Control-Click (I have my Command/Ctrl swapped and at-a-glance I'll forget which is which). It is indeed *not* Spanish for "Configure Folder Actions...".

Comment: Isn't it Galician? That's what Google Translate's auto-detect says.

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution but still don't know what caused it. I had my language settings set with "Canadian English" at the top if the list. I moved English to the top of the list, logged out and in, and the problem us gone.

Feels like whatever app us adding that last entry in my menu (I'm not near my Mac right now but I think it was an Automater menu item) doesn't like the Canadian English language locale.

It wasn't always that way though. It seems to enf up changing after some period of time. Oh well. Problem solved for now. If I can reproduce it reliably I might try to figure out what causes it to switch like that.